# how can i use two types of queryset models override save method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i want to ask you if i POST an article with featured=True then the old featured=true get transferred to featured=false queryset. i just want two `[:2]` values in featured=true queryset. [here is the example of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQlfp.png)
there are two article in featured=true queryset which i want the second article automatically get updated to featured=false when i create new article.

the output of my code when i applied is featuring only one [article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9vk9.png). were as i want two articles to be featured.

Here is the query of [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNEoE.png) with `print(featured_articles.count())`, photo of the list of articles in the [admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fwAl.png), and the [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmAVk.png).

models.py

```
    class ArticleQuerySet(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super(ArticleQuerySet,self).get_queryset().filter(status=True)


    class Article(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       author = models.ForeignKey(
       User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
       thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='def.jpg',
                                upload_to='article/thumbnails')
       timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
       featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
       tags = TaggableManager()
       objects = models.Manager()
       status_objects = ArticleQuerySet()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-timestamp']

     # i also try this method
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.featured == True:
                Article.objects.filter(pk__in=(Article.objects.filter(featured=True,
                 ).values_list('pk',flat=True)[:2])).update(featured=False)
                self.featured = True
            super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article


def index(request):
    featured_articles = Article.status_objects.filter(tags__exact='1', featured=True)[:2]
    regular_articles = Article.status_objects.filter(tags__exact='1').exclude(pk__in=featured_articles)

    context = {
        'featured': featured_articles,
        'regular': regular_articles,
    }

    return render(request, 'news/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
    <!--post header-->
    <div class="post-head">
        <h2 class="title"> Article </h2>
    </div>
    <!-- post body -->
    <div class="post-body">
        <div class="">
            <!-- item one -->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 main-post-inner bord-right">
                        {% for nat in featured %}
                        <article>
                            <figure>
                                <a href="{% url 'news-detail' pk=nat.pk %}"><img src="{{ nat.thumbnail.url }}"
                                        height="242" width="345" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="post-info">
                                <h3><a href="#">{{ nat.title }}</a>
                                </h3>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="ti-timer"></i>
                                    {{ nat.timestamp | timesince }}
                                </span>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="news-list">
                            {% for nat in regular %}
                            <div class="news-list-item">
                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                    <a href="{% url 'news-detail' pk=nat.pk %}" class="thumb">
                                        <img src="{{ nat.thumbnail.url }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        <div class="link-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-info-2">
                                    <h5><a href="{% url 'news-detail' pk=nat.pk %}" class="title">{{ nat.title }}</a>
                                    </h5>
                                    <i class="ti-timer"></i> {{ nat.timestamp | timesince }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, but you did mention your Y, so I added an alternative solution to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but the standard way of doing this is keeping all marked as featured as is, without marking previous featured articles as `featured=False`:

views.py

```
def articles(self):
    featured_articles = Article.status_objects.filter(tags__exact='1', featured=True)[:2]
    regular_articles = Article.status_objects.filter(tags__exact='1').exclude(pk__in=featured_articles)
    ...
```

Note how `.exclude(featured=True)` is not in the `regular_articles` queryset. Old featured articles will automatically rollover into this queryset.

Some advantages of this approach are:

1. No need to maintain the list of featured articles
2. You get to keep a list of previously featured articles
3. You don't run into race conditions when multiple articles are being added/featured
4. You don't bother the database with updates
5. Your code is easier to maintain and read
6. Updating a single article doesn't have side effects (e.g. when you update an article, you know for sure you are only updating that article, nothing else)

That being said, there are times when you actually want to mark them as `featured=false`, but unless you have a compelling reason to, it's usually better to keep things simpler.

Comment: i want two articles to be mentioned instead of one. [i want this modification to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQlfp.png)

Comment: the output of my code when i applied is featuring only one [article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9vk9.png) . were as i want two articles to be featured....

Comment: Update your question with your template file and the entirety of your view. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Hi, quick glance, your templates look good, but how about your database? Can share a photo of the list of articles in the admin? Or can you run a `print(featured_articles.count())` inside your view?

Comment: Okay, only 1 is showing because only 1 article is marked as featured. Try marking 2 or more as featured, and you'll see that only the latest 2 articles will appear as featured in your template

Comment: yes! i want to marking 2 or more as featured and that only the latest 2 or more

Comment: Yeah, go to your admin, and mark multiple articles as featured. Then refresh your code and you will see that only two will show in your page

Comment: When you create a new create a new article, just marked is featured. This will push out the previously 2nd featured article to being the 3rd featured article. So the previously 1st featured article and the new ones will now be the 2 latest featured articles.

Answer (score 0):

There is more better way for this. Create One new model like this.
remove featured field from your article model.

```
class featured (models.Model):
    featured=models.OneToOneField(Article, related_name='featured', on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

create as much featured article you want to featured.
suppose you want only two featured article, then create only two record.

whenever you want to change your featured article just update that record.
i hope this will be simple design and very flexible also you can increase featured article as much as you want by just adding new record and decrease as much as you want by just delete. 
here you don't want to override your article save method.